# Python creating a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary whose values are lists.  For example:

```
{
  1: ['1'],
  2: ['1','2'],
  3: ['2']
}
```

If I do:

```
d = dict()
a = ['1', '2']
for i in a:
    for j in range(int(i), int(i) + 2): 
        d[j].append(i)
```

I get a KeyError, because d[...] isn't a list.  In this case, I can add the following code after the assignment of a to initialize the dictionary.

```
for x in range(1, 4):
    d[x] = list()
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Lets say I don't know the keys I am going to need until I am in the second `for` loop.  For example:

```
class relation:
    scope_list = list()
...
d = dict()
for relation in relation_list:
    for scope_item in relation.scope_list:
        d[scope_item].append(relation)
```

An alternative would then be replacing

```
d[scope_item].append(relation)
```

with

```
if d.has_key(scope_item):
    d[scope_item].append(relation)
else:
    d[scope_item] = [relation,]
```

What is the best way to handle this?  Ideally, appending would "just work".  Is there some way to express that I want a dictionary of empty lists, even if I don't know every key when I first create the list?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

You can use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> a = ['1', '2']
>>> for i in a:
...   for j in range(int(i), int(i) + 2):
...     d[j].append(i)
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['1'], 2: ['1', '2'], 3: ['2']})
>>> d.items()
[(1, ['1']), (2, ['1', '2']), (3, ['2'])]
```

Comment: Other dictionaries under the `collections` module also work this way, for example `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: Oh. This is great. And you don't have to initialize to '= []'. Good stuff!

Comment: `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

Answer (score 60):

You can build it with list comprehension like this:

```
>>> dict((i, range(int(i), int(i) + 2)) for i in ['1', '2'])
{'1': [1, 2], '2': [2, 3]}
```

And for the second part of your question use [defaultdict](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/defaultdict-examples.html)

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
        d[k].append(v)

>>> d.items()
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

Answer (score 41):

You can use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
d = dict()
a = ['1', '2']
for i in a:
    for j in range(int(i), int(i) + 2): 
        d.setdefault(j, []).append(i)

print d  # prints {1: ['1'], 2: ['1', '2'], 3: ['2']}
```

The rather oddly-named `setdefault` function says "Get the value with this key, or if that key isn't there, add this value and then return it."

As others have rightly pointed out, `defaultdict` is a better and more modern choice.  `setdefault` is still useful in older versions of Python (prior to 2.5).

Comment: This works, but it's usually preferred to use defaultdict when it's available.

Comment: @David, yeah, setdefault wasn't the most brilliant bit of design, sorry -- it's hardly ever the best choice. I do think we (the Python committers) redeemed our collective reputation with collections.defaultdict, though;-).

Comment: @DavidZ, setdefault is different from defaultdict, as it's more flexible: otherwhise, how do you specify different default values for different dictionary keys?

Comment: @AlexGidan That's true, but not particularly relevant to this question.

Comment: This answer is also useful when you need an OrderedDict and a default value.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I just use JSON to convert things to strings and back.  Strings I understand.

```
import json
s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
mydict = {}
hash = json.dumps(s)
mydict[hash] = "whatever"
print mydict
#{'[["yellow", 1], ["blue", 2], ["yellow", 3], ["blue", 4], ["red", 1]]': 'whatever'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question has already been answered, but IIRC you can replace lines like:

```
if d.has_key(scope_item):
```

with:

```
if scope_item in d:
```

That is, `d` references `d.keys()` in that construction. Sometimes `defaultdict` isn't the best option (for example, if you want to execute multiple lines of code after the `else` associated with the above `if`), and I find the `in` syntax easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

easy way is:

```
a = [1,2]
d = {}
for i in a:
  d[i]=[i, ]

print(d)
{'1': [1, ], '2':[2, ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create it from a list, you can also use dict comprehension with a list comprehension within it:

```
dict_of_list_values = {len(k): [name for name in names if len(name) == len(k)] for k in names}
```

(I used a list of names for this example)