# put lists inside dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to put `list`s inside a `dictionary`. I want do like this:

```
trail = {[]}

for i in states:
    for j in states:
        if(max_val < temp_V[j][i]):
            max_val = temp_V[j][i]
            trail[i].append(j)
```

But I am getting an error at `trail = {[]}`. I'm new to Python. How can I do this?

Comment: `{[]}` is a set not dictionary, sets can't contain unhashable values.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960733/python-creating-a-dictionary-of-lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
trail = defaultdict(list)
```

It will construct an empty list for any key when you try to access it for the first time so

```
trail[i].append(j)
```

will work as expectd. As for:

```
trail = {[]}
```

You need to have a keys and corresponding values for a valid dictionary literal eg.

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

`{[]}` trys to makes a `set` instead eg.

```
>>> {1}
set([1])
```

but sets only support hashable items, see [*hash table*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), and a list (which can be modified) is therefore not hashable.