# Python - dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

Which is the best way to make a dictionary of lists? 
For instance, if I have lists *list1, list2* and want to make a dictionary *my_dict* like that:

```
my_dict = ['list1': list1, 'list2': list2]
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960733/python-creating-a-dictionary-of-lists) example but the best answer is written in 2009. Maybe there are some new more laconic ways to do this?

Comment: You need to use curly rather than square brackets, but otherwise this is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: Plus one for laconic as a synonym for pythonic :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use curly rather than square brackets, but otherwise this is probably as good as it gets:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_dict = {'list1': list1, 'list2': list2}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a dictionary of lists, consider a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

A **normal dictionary** works fine, but it raises an error if a key is not found.

```
list1 = list("abcd")
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]


d = {"list1": list1, "list2": list2}
d["list3"]
# KeyError: 'list3'
```

This may be disruptive in some applications and may require additional exception handling.

The **`defaultdict`** behaves like a normal dict while adding some protection against errors.

```
import collections as ct


dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
dd.update(d)
dd
# defaultdict(list, {'list1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'list2': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

Adding a missing key will call the default factory function, i.e. `list`.  Here instead of a error, we get an empty container:

```
dd["list3"]
# []
```

This entry was added with an empty list.

```
dd
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'list1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
#              'list2': [1, 2, 3, 4],
#              'list3': []})
```

Convert a `defaultdict` to a regular dict by setting the default factory to `None`

```
dd.default_factory = None
dd
# defaultdict(None, {'list1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'list2': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

or by using the `dict()` builtin:

```
dict(dd)
# {'list1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'list2': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to turn the variable name into a key, here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python).

If you just want a dictionary of lists with a sequential key.

```
def turn_to_dict(*args):
    return {i: v for i, v in enumerate(args)}

lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst2 = [3, 4, 6, 7]
lst3 = [5, 8, 9]

v = turn_to_dict(lst1, lst2, lst3)

>>> print(v)
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [3, 4, 6, 7], 2: [5, 8, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, very succinct. Curly braces, not square brackets.

I think that's the shortest way around it.

```
list1 = [5, 500, 543]
list2 = [4, 4, 4]

my_dict = {'list1':list1, 'list2': list2}
```

Comment: Matchematics can do that to a person ;-/  Turn that fron upside down :-)

Comment: It's exactly the opposite, Mawg. Don't read too much into it -- the emoji isn't for you.

Comment: Gld to ehar it  :-) "Stand on head make smiel from frown - but rest of face now upside down"

Answer (score 0):

Use the curly brace syntax to define the dictionary, and give each entry in your dictionary a key that corresponds to each value:

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_b = [6,7,8,9,10]

my_dict = {'list1':list_a, 'list2':list_b}
```

[More in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
my_dict = dict([('list1', list1), ('list2', list2)])
```

Or, alternatively:

```
my_dict = {'list1': list1, 'list2': list2}
```

The result will be the same.