# convert multiple lists to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Is there a way in python to turn a set of lists into a dictionary, where the name of the list is the key and the values are the values? Can you do this with dictionary comprehension?

```
one = ['a', 'b', 'c']
two = ['d','e','f']
```

would become

```
dictionary = {"one" : ['a', 'b', 'c'], "two":['d','e','f'] }
```

Comment: a set of lists? like the type `set`?.....

Comment: You'd have to show how these are populated. Is 'one' the name of a variable? An argument to a function?

Comment: "one" is not the "name of the list."  List objects have no such concept.  "one" is the name of a Python variable bound to the list, but you could equally well have assigned to a variable named "three" and it would still be the same list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770836/python-dictionary-of-lists)

Comment: `dict(zip(["one", "two"], [one, two]))`

Comment: You can basically wrap the function `dict` around what you typed: dict(one=['a', 'b', 'c'], two = ['d','e','f'])

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> one = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> two = ['d','e','f']
>>> c = dict({'one':one, 'two':two})
```

or

```
>>> dict(zip(["one", "two"], [one, two]))
```

Why you want to convert *one* variable to 'one' and *two* variable to 'two' is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can necessarily access the variable name, but lets say, if you had a list of those lists, you could set the index of each one as the key value. example:

```
megaList = [[2, 3, 6], [3, 6, 1]]
dic = {}
for i, l in enumerate(megaList):
    dic[i] = l
```

but in that case you might as well just have the list of lists. Just though I'd share since I'm not sure what you're trying to do, and maybe this can steer you in the right direction.

Or do what @enigma did, if you don't mind typing them out by hand.