# Can you append a list to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I need to create a list which will save the users inputs (a name and their 3 scores) and that will then append this information to one of 3 files. I tried doing this by appending the data to a list and then the list to a dictionary but this doesn't seem to work. I am really new to python so would really appreciate any help.
This is my code so far:

```
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
dict3 = {}
list1 = []
list2 =[]
list3 =[]

def main():
    name= input ('What is your name?')
    for i in range(0,3)
        score = input("Enter your score: ")
        clss =input('which class?')
        if clss==1:
            list1.append (name, score)
        elif clss==2:
            list2.append (name, score)
        elif clss==3:
            list3.append (name, score)
```

Here I want to append the list to one of 3 dictionaries depending on the class:

```
def loop():
    x=input('Do you want to make an entry?')
    if x=='Yes':
        main()
    elif x=='No':
        sys.exit(0)  

loop()
```

Comment: dict1={"Entry":list1}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have lists in dictionary to be able to append to them. You can do something like:

```
scores = {"class1": [], "class2": [], "class3": []} 

def main():
    name= input ('What is your name?')
    for i in range(0,3)
        score = input("Enter your score: ")
        clss =input('which class?')
        if clss==1:
            scores["class1"].append({"name": name, "score": score}) 
        elif clss==2:
            scores["class2"].append({"name": name, "score": score}) 
        elif clss==3:
            scores["class3"].append({"name": name, "score": score}) 
    print scores
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use defaultdict ?
Example  from the python docs:

```
>>> s = 'mississippi'
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for k in s:
...     d[k] += 1
...
>>> d.items()
[('i', 4), ('p', 2), ('s', 4), ('m', 1)]
```

You can see another example of using defaultdict [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/960753/4278243)

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = {i:x for i,x in enumerate([['List', 'one'],['List', 'two']])}
```

A somewhat different approach would be this, I'm unsure if this is what you mean but I tried my best understanding. I also tried keeping it as simple as possible.

```
d = {}

while True:
    # Ask the user to make a new entry.
    raw = raw_input('Make a new entry?')

    if raw.lower() in ['y', 'yes']: 
        # Ask the users name.
        name = raw_input('Your name?')

        # Create new entrypoint in the dictionary containing a empty list bound to the name
        d[name] = []

        for score in range(3):
            # Ask the user for three scores
            d[name].append(raw_input('Enter a new score: '))

   # If the input doesn't match you break out of the loop.
    else:
        break

    # You can at any time print the contents of the dictionary.
    # print d
```