# How to iteratively append key-value pairs to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict1 = {}

for item in list1:
   dict1.update({"letter": item})

print(dict1)
```

I want to iterate over the list and add each element into the dictionary with the same key for each element. So in this case, the required output should be:

```
{'letter': 'a', 'letter': 'b', 'letter': 'c'}
```

But the output I get is:

```
{'letter': 'c'}
```

Only the last element is added to the dict. How can I get the required output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dictonary can not have duplicate key

Comment: you sure you dont want `{'a':'letter','b':'letter','c':'letter'}` ? since that is possible ...

Comment: If you want multiple items per key, give each key a list of values rather than an atomic value.

Comment: What about a list of unique dictionaries, like so: [{"letter": "a"}, {"letter": "b"}, {"letter": "c"}] @vignesh Kalai

Comment: You could certainly do that, but you shouldn't want to.

Comment: I am working on implementing the NB classifier using NLTK like [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/classify.html). The features are taken as a list of tuples; within each tuple, there is a dictionary and a string to represent the class label.The dictionaries seem to have the same keys.. @TigerhawkT3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960733/python-creating-a-dictionary-of-lists

Comment: You might want to use the dictionary initiated list. Then the key will store a list of values. You can use defaultdict from collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sa=[{"letter":a} for in list1]
sa
[{"letter":a},{"letter":b},{"letter":c}]
```

But there is no need to do this though

The right method would be to add a list to the key `letter`

```
dict1={"letter":[]}
dict1["letter"].extend([a for a in list1])
dict
{"letter":["a","b","c"]}
```

Comment: This is almost certainly solving [Problem Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What's the benefit of showing the output of an unnecessary operation?

Comment: I don't understand how it's an answer in the slightest, but it looks like you've helped someone solve his [Problem Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Experimentation is never wrong. @Vignesh Kalai