# python create dict using list of strings with length of strings as values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm sure this can be done, but I have thus far been unsuccessful:

I have a list of strings.  I want to create a dictionary with the length of said strings (which can be expressed as a range) as the key and the string itself as the value.

example:
Here's something like the list I have:  ['foo','bar','help','this','guy']

I'd like to end up with a dictionary like this:
{3:['foo','bar','guy], 4:['this','help']}

Comment: I seen a similar stack overflow questioned answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960733/python-creating-a-dictionary-of-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary as a container with `setdefault`:

```
lst = ['foo','bar','help','this','guy'] 

result = {}   
for w in lst:
    result.setdefault(len(w), []).append(w)

result
# {3: ['foo', 'bar', 'guy'], 4: ['help', 'this']}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `defaultdict` so you don't have to check whether or not to create the list for a new key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = ['foo','bar','help','this','guy']

len_dict = defaultdict(list)

for word in x:
    len_dict[len(word)].append(word)

len_dict
#
# Out[5]: defaultdict(list, {3: ['foo', 'bar', 'guy'], 4: ['help', 'this']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
d={}
lst=['foo','bar','help','this','guy']
for i in lst:
    if len(i) in d:
        d[len(i)].append(i)
    else:
        d[len(i)]=[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is pythonic, elegant and fast: (by the Famous **Raymond Hettinger** in one of his many [conferences](https://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go?list=PLNCAWk9FlhOexHjVNQNQ18xvdTuwcR0pu&t=1605)).

`dict.setdefault` is the dictionary method that **initialises** a key-value if the key is not found in dict as well as performing `dict.get` for **provided key**.

```
l = ['foo','bar','help','this','guy']
d = {}
for e in l:
    key = len(e)
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(name)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{3: ['foo', 'bar', 'guy'], 4: ['help', 'this']}
```

This solution is the modern way of the solution above:

`defaultdict` from `collection` is a subclass of `dict` that automatically initialises value to any given key that is not in the `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = ['foo','bar','help','this','guy']
d = defaultdict(list)
for e in l:
    key = len(e)
    d[key].append(e)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {3: ['foo', 'bar', 'guy'], 4: ['help', 'this']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what have been said, but using the `get` method of `dict` class:

```
the_list=['foo','bar','help','this','guy']
d = {}
for word in the_list:
  key = len(word)
  d[key] = d.get(key, []) + [word]
print(d)
# {3: ['foo', 'bar', 'guy'], 4: ['help', 'this']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict
given_list=['foo','bar','help','this','guy']
len_words=[len(i) for i in given_list]
d=defaultdict(list)
for i,j in list(zip(len_words,given_list)):
    d[i].append(j)
```